# Stop squashing syslog debug messages on OS X

Tags: macos, logging, syslog

I'm using syslog to capture logging from an application. I've configured syslog to write my applications logs to an application-specific file in `asl.conf`:

```
# Redirect foo to /var/log/foo.log
? [= Sender foo] file /var/log/foo.log
```

This works, but repeated messages are culled. For example:

```
Jun 21 17:22:03 hostname.domain foo[346] <Debug>:   This is a message!
Jun 21 17:22:03 --- last message repeated 3 times ---
```

How can I disable the squashing of repeated messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you restart the syslogd daemon with the option -dup_delay and set the value to 0, it will stop this happening, but it's there to prevent the log getting filled with unnecessary messages.

More detail of syslogd is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/syslogd.8.html).

Comment: It looks like you can set per-sender dup_delays in `asl.conf`, rather than disabling `dup_delay` on everything logged by `syslogd`. My solution was to address the need for duplicate logging in the application rather than mess with `syslogd`.